# How to execute android application Application in same emulator rather than new emulator every time I run the application?

Tags: android, emulation

In eclipse When I run android application it always Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'xxx'.
But I want to run current running emulator.

How to make it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your application Target mode has set to manual. To solve :

> Right Click on your project-> Run as -> Select Run Configurations -> In that select Target
>   Tab ->Select Automatic instead of manual
>
> Click on Apply and run.

hope it help you.

Comment: @SagarZala your welcome..,you can rank this answer by tick...

Answer (score 2):

Right click on project->Run As->Run configuration->select Tab Target->select Radio button " always prompt to pick device" ....

so it will always give prompt to select emulator....

I hop it will work for u...

Comment: U are welcome my friend...

Answer (score 0):

All right in the **project explorer** Right click on your project and goto **RunAs**..->**Run Configuration**. Then goto the **target** tab. I think you might have some miss-configurations there. Just choose the option that best suits you.
 Hope it helps. Just let me know if you still can't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps it will help you.

Try this,

Just Right click your **Project name** --> **Run As**--> **Run Configurations** --> **Target Tab** --> **pick up Always prompt to pick device** --> **Apply** / **Run**.

Answer (score 0):

Select "Choose a running Android Device" while running

And close the adt application from your task manager

If that also doesn't work click reset your adt from eclipse devices